# If code changed to std::move(vector) will that save a copy operation in this function

Tags: c++, move-semantics

The function is to extract the file contents into a vector as below:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> GetFileContents(const std::string& filename)
{
    std::ifstream file(filename, std::ios::binary);
    if (!file.good())
    {
        return {};
    }
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    std::streampos fileSize = file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::vector<uint8_t> fileData(fileSize);
    file.read((char*) &fileData[0], fileSize);
    return fileData;
}
```

On the lines:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> fileData(fileSize);
file.read((char*) &fileData[0], fileSize);
return fileData;
```

The fileData vector is copied into a temporary vector to be returned here?

Do I need to change to:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> fileData(fileSize);
file.read((char*) &fileData[0], fileSize);
return std::move(fileData);
```

to do a move and save a vector copy operation?

Any other changes required in the function to support move?

Is there any value in std::move({}) for the empty case?

Comment: Maybe `std::move()` should be called where this function is being called. Like `auto ret = std::move(GetFileContents("some_file.txt"));`

Comment: @kiner_shah This is superfluous. If a function returns by value, its call is an rvalue expression by itself.

Comment: @DanielLangr, yes that makes sense, then it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you shouldn't use `std::move` there.

That avoids possible [NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), and there is an implicit move anyway.

See [Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters) for further detail.

Comment: There are some rather clear advices from Scott Meyers specifically on this topic.